# Prevent Users from Switching Sites in CP with Multi Site Manager

Tags: multi-site-manager

Does anyone know if it is possible to hide the 'Switch sites' links in the CP for certain member groups?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to simply hide the dropdowns in CSS

```
li.parent msm_sites ul{display:none}
```

You'd also have to do some overrides for the arrow that appears when you click it but that would get you what you needed. I don't *believe* there is another way of doing this. But I'd love to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible without at best a plugin or at worst altering main EE code (don't do this).

I understand why you might want to remove the option to change sites, however if you are concerned about certain member groups seeing too much in the control panel, you can of course replicate the control panel posting functionality using [Safecracker](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html) where you can totally control the page that the user sees.

Comment: Thanks Jon and Mark. We're giving access to the CP to colleagues in Germany but we only want them to be able to edit the DE site, and similarly we only want UK staff to edit the UK site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authorize ony for one specific subsite i would sugest you create a specific membergroup. Since membergroup settings are site specific you can authorize for only one subsite, members in this group will nolonger be able to switch to the other sites..